# What does this type of generic class in Java means?

Tags: java, generics

I already know the basics of Generics in Java but this one confuses me...

What does this mean in Java?

```
public class SampleClass<Integer> {
    ....
}


public class UserClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleClass<String> s = new SampleClass<>();
    }
}
```

this one compiles without errors.

I thought that when you are creating a generic class in java, you only have to use a single capital letter in doing it. For example:

```
public class SampleClass<T>  {
    ....
}
```

But why does java allows constructing a generic class with a specific type parameter, like the first one I've written which uses an `Integer` type parameter?

And why is it that when I instantiated the `SampleClass`in `UserClass`, it accepts a `String` type as a type parameter when I constructed the class `SampleClass` type parameter as `Integer`? I thought this was going to trigger an error since the `SampleClass` was constructed with an `Integer` type parameter.

Can someone please enlighten me on this one? I'm a little confused with this. Thanks...

Comment: Where did you see this example?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- in the book Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick, The book uses this type of code

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- although `Integer` is not the exact type used in the class

Comment: Well ... some book authors are "a law unto themselves" :-)

Comment: @StephenC but this type of coding is definitely a bad practice. Is it?

Comment: It is a matter of opinion.  However, clearly it has confused you ... and (IMO) it would most likely confuse (and irritate!) the majority of practicing Java developers.  Draw your own conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that when you are creating a generic class in java, you only have to use a single capital letter in doing it.

That is incorrect.

The Java Language Specification allows you to use any identifier for the generic type variables.  Use of a single capital letter (or a very short all-caps name) is *just a Java style convention*, albeit an important one.

So in your example, you have used `Integer` as the name of the type variable.  That is liable to cause confusion for someone reading your code, and problem for you if you also needed to refer to the standard `Integer` class within `SampleClass`.

Comment: I've seen this code in Robert Sedgwick's book Algorithms. I am a little confused with the style of coding used in that book

Comment: Well Robert probably should read standard Java Style Guides more closely.  However,  he is free to write anything he wants in his books ... provided that his editor doesn't pull him up.  My advice to you is to not copy that aspect of his style.

Answer (score 3):

The *convention* is to use a single letter for type variables, but that's not a requirement; type variables can be any Java identifier. (`ID` as a type variable is a frequent exception to the convention.) You're declaring a type variable named `Integer` that is shadowing `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

As other have already pointed out you used `Integer` where one would normally use `T` for `Type`, just like one would normally use conventional

`K` for `key`

`E` for `element`

`V` for `value`

It's just a convention. Also it's pretty common to use the `S`, `U`, `V` if there are more generic type parameters

If you want to set bounds on your generic class so that it only accepts numeric types then you would use something like this

```
class SampleClass<T extends Number>{}
```